# Неясное поведение шаблонов

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, метапрограммирование

Есть следующая шаблонная функция:

```
template<class func, class ...Args>
auto func_wrapper_to_bool(func &&_Fn, Args &&... args)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_member_function_pointer<func>::value)
        return func_wrapper_to_bool(std::mem_fn(std::forward<func>(_Fn)), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    else
    {
        if constexpr (std::is_same<decltype(_Fn(std::forward<Args>(args)...)), bool>::value)
            return [&]()->bool {return _Fn(std::forward<Args>(args)...); };
        else
            return [&]()->bool {_Fn(std::forward<Args>(args)...); return true; };
    }
}
```

В моём коде она требуется для того, чтобы обернуть любую функцию, которая возвращает не bool в функцию которая возвращает bool

У меня есть класс

```
class Test
{
public:
    void switcher(int i)
    {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Cool!!!" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

В функции main я вызываю функцию следующим образом:

```
int main()
{
    Test ts;

    auto mem_fn = func_wrapper_to_bool(std::mem_fn(&Test::switcher), ts, 1);
    mem_fn();

    auto not_mem_fn = func_wrapper_to_bool(&Test::switcher,ts,2);
    not_mem_fn();
}
```

При компиляции релиз версии программа отлично отрабатывает, а при компиляции дебаг версии вылетает при вызове оператора() у not_mem_fn. С чем это может быть связанно ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну так ваш внутренний

```
std::mem_fn(std::forward<func>(_Fn))
```

это временный объект, который заведомо будет уничтожен еще до выхода из вашего `func_wrapper_to_bool`. А вы его захватываете *по ссылке* в лямбду.

Потом при вызове через `not_mem_fn`, возвращенного из `func_wrapper_to_bool`, лямбда обращается к этому объекту через ссылку, а он уже уничтожен. Та же проблема имеет место и с первым вызовом - переданный снаружи временный `std::mem_fn(&Test::switcher)` тоже уничтожается еще до вызова вашего `mem_fn()`.

И с аргументами та же проблема. В момент вызова `func_wrapper_to_bool` значения `1` и `2` существуют только в виде временных объектов. Лямбда захватывает их *по ссылке*, а к моменту фактических вызовов они уже уничтожены.

Comment: А вы не подскажете, как можно решить данную проблему ?

Comment: @Fqqlt, можно использовать копирование вместо захвата по ссылке.

Comment: @Fqqlt: Захватывать по значению. Но если начать все огульно захватывать по значению, то у вас и сам объект `ts` будет захватываться по значению. Это значит, в частности, что внутри не-mutable lambda он станет константным и вызвать метод `switcher` вы не сможете. Придется либо передавать с помощью `std::ref`, либо делать отдельную обработку первого аргумента для методов классов.

Comment: Я так подумал над своей проблемой и понял, что для моих нужд хватит лишь функции, которая оборачивает функцию класса, которая ничего не принимает, спасибо всем за объяснение и советы,насколько я понял "универсальную" обёртку для произвольной невозможно сделать, из-за того, что невозможно узнать для каких объектов требуется копирование, а для каких просто захват по ссылке ?

Comment: @Fqqlt: Не что значит "невозхможно"? Еще раз, один из вариантов: это подход, использованный в `std::thread` и в `std::bind`. Все всегда захватывается только *по значению*. А если пользователя это не устраивает, то он сам использует либо указатели, либо `std::ref`. То есть пользователь сам организует захват ссылки ("по значению"), а обертка вообще не беспокоится ни о чем и не пытается ничего "узнать". Вся ответственность за время жизни и т.п. целиком лежит на пользователе.